# Why is this for loop not logging sum?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to use this for loop within the function to get the sum of an array. However, when I call the function I receive NaN.

```
tips = [1,2,3,4,5]
function sumTip (tips){
  for (i=0; i<tips.length; i++){
    var total = total + tips[i];
    console.log(total);
  }
}
sumTip();
```

Comment: It should be `tips.length` not `length.tips`

Comment: What @adiga says. And give the array as an attribute with your function. `sumTip(tips);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Error 1** - Wrong syntax. It should be `tips.length` and not `length.tips`.
- **Error 2** - You haven't given the parameter to the function when you
  are calling it. It should be `sumTip(tips);`
- **Error 3** - `i` is not declared in the loop.
- Error 4 - For your logic to work, the `total` should be declared and initialised to zero outside the for loop and then used inside the loop.

You are doing - `var total = total + tips[i];` when total hasn't been defined yet so the in the expression `total + tips[i]` evaluates to NaN and that's why you are getting Nan as output.

The following code should work after correcting the above mentioned errors -

```
tips = [1,2,3,4,5]
function sumTip (tips){
  var total = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<tips.length; i++){  
    total = total + tips[i];      
    console.log(total);
  }
}
sumTip(tips);
```

Comment: You need to initialize `total` before using it.

Comment: Just to add, you won't errors if you don't declare `i` in the `for()` loop but it's always a best practice to declare a variable or else it will automatically get global-scoped and may cause some problems as your project grows

Answer (score 1):

Couple problems you're running into here. First, in your last line, when you call `sumTip`, you never pass it the array, like: `sumTip(tips)`. Second, you are resetting `total` everytime you loop, it should be set up like:

```
var total = 0;

for (var i=0; i<tips.length; i++){
    total += tips[i];
    console.log(total);
  }
```

This all could just be reduced though: `let sum = tips.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)`